# Time Series Prediction with Partial Future Data (Presales)

Tags: time-series, forecasting, predictive-models, arima

I have a data set that contains tickets sold up to a certain point in time, and then presold tickets for future events. Just for demonstrative purposes, I'll use the Australian total wine sales data set.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pmdarima as pm

data = pm.datasets.load_wineind(as_series=True)
data.index = pd.to_datetime(data.index, format='%b %Y')
past, future = pm.model_selection.train_test_split(data, train_size=150)

np.random.seed(1)
future = future.reset_index()
future.rename({'index': 'Date', 0:'Sales'}, axis=1, inplace=True)
future['Presales'] = future['Sales'] - np.random.uniform(1000)*future.index
```

[image]

We have some tickets sold for future events already, but we'll sell a few more tickets for events that are happening in the near future and (hopefully) many more for events in the future. Now, I've no problem fitting a SARIMA model using past observations:

```
model = pm.auto_arima(past, start_p=1, start_q=1, max_p=3, max_q=3, m=12,
                             start_P=0, seasonal=True, d=1, D=1, trace=True,
                             error_action='ignore', suppress_warnings=True,
                             stepwise=True)
```

But this completely ignores the useful presale information that I already have. Is there a way to incorporate this into my SARIMA model?

UPDATE:
I actually am able to obtain snapshots of what ticket sales looked like on previous dates. For example, if I pull the data for 2 random days, say, 1/5/23 and 3/14/23, it would look like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': pd.date_range(start = '1/1/23', end='1/5/23'), 
                   'total sales for all events on 1/5/23':[0, 10, 30, 50, 100]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'date': pd.date_range(start = '3/10/23', end='3/14/23'), 
                   'total sales for all events on 3/14/23':[0, 30, 40, 80, 85]}) 

df
    date        sales for all events on 1/5/23
0   2023-01-01  0
1   2023-01-02  10
2   2023-01-03  30
3   2023-01-04  50
4   2023-01-05  100

df2
    date        total sales for all events on 3/14/23
0   2023-03-10  0
1   2023-03-11  30
2   2023-03-12  40
3   2023-03-13  80
4   2023-03-14  85
```

Presumably this helps me greatly. Is the correct procedure then to engineer some features (I'm thinking month, list of events actually on the day in question (5/1/23 and 14/4/23), etc) and then to fit an RNN/LSTM, and the to use this to predict sales for future dates (tomorrow onwards)? I know that just trying this myself would answer my question, but the data I have is of course a lot more complicated than this toy example and don't want to waste time if there's a flaw in that approach.